# How can I create all possible combinations from dynamic attributes?

Tags: javascript

I need to generate all possible combinantions of attributeValues from the following list of attributes

```
attributes:[
 {
  attributeName:"Color of leg",
  attributeValues:[blue,green,black]
 },
 {
  attributeName:"Color of hand",
  attributeValues:[blue,orange,white]
 },
 {
  attributeName:"Color of nose",
  attributeValues:[red,orange]
 }
]
```

Occurence of attributeName and related attributeValues in the list can vary so "fixed depth of for" isn't applicable. I currently struggle with this quite a long time and can't move forward. I have no idea how to deal with

Desired result is:

```
object=[{colorOfLeg:"blue",colorOfHand:"blue",colorOfNose:"red"},
        {colorOfLeg:"blue",colorOfHand:"blue",colorOfNose:"orange"},
        {colorOfLeg:"green",colorOfHand:"blue",colorOfNose:"red"},
        etc...
       ]
```

the way how attributes list looks like isn't mandatory to keep. 
I would appreciate your help

*****************************  UPDATE

Input form of data changed to:

```
 dynamicAttributes:[
     {attrName:"Color of hand",attrValue:"blue",index:1}, 
     {attrName:"Color of hand",attrValue:"orange",index:2},
     {attrName:"Color of hand",attrValue:"purple",index:3},

     {attrName:"Color of nose",attrValue:"blue",index:4},   
     {attrName:"Color of nose",attrValue:"white",index:5},

     {attrName:"Color of leg",attrValue:"blue",index:6},   
     {attrName:"Color of leg",attrValue:"white",index:7}
    ]
```

Afterwards I found out all unique attrName (Color of leg,Color of nose, Color of hand).From unique name I generate list of arrays where each contains indexes grouped by unique attrName.

```
indexGroups=[[1,2,3],[4,5],[6,7]]
```

I guess the stuff I am looking for is "Cartesian product". I can imagine "static logic" if number of unique attrName would be contstant but don't know how to create the dynamic logic for this case

***************************** UPDATE2

I found the function in another stackoverflow thread:

```
const f = (a, b) => [].concat(...a.map(d => b.map(e => [].concat(d, e))));
const cartesian = (a, b, ...c) => (b ? cartesian(f(a, b), ...c) : a);
```

Calling "cartesian" with all arrays will produce all possible combinations.

```
cartesian([1,2,3],[4,5],[6,7])
```

I fully don't understand the function. Could anyone explain? Especially the f function

Comment: Try using nested .map. First level to iterate through the items in the list of of attributes and then the next .map to iterate through the attributeValues. Have a look on MDN for some examples.

Comment: Hello Teej, thx for anwer. If i am correct, the itteration would return attributeName and all attributeValues but how to combine all attributeValues (from color of nose, color of leg etc..)  together ?